# Can't use annotation @data in maven

Tags: java, maven, annotations, lombok

Let me know how to lombok annotation? Why not, I can't use only @Data annotation?

[image]

Comment: My System Eclipse / Maven / Spring.
lombok is version Project Lombok » 1.16.6
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.6</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also install the Lombok plugin on your IDE. Since it doesn't know that some code is generated for you at build time, it will report problems.

Have a look at http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJan2010.html#installation for installation instructions.

Comment: You use Maven dependencies to include Lombok in the project itself. Building the project should actually work fine with only the dependencies. The IDE plugin is so that Eclipse is aware of Lombok and doesn't give you warnings in the code. So you kind of need to do both, or be willing to live with the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this dependency. Latest version has an issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.20</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```